# Use Wizards with Project Templates

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wizard

I'm trying to create a wizard for my project template like the one demonstrated below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301.aspx

This great example shows how to add custom parameters to a project. What I want to do is allow the user to select which files should be added to the new project from the template. example: On a particular project being built from the template, a user does not want to include linq assemblies and references because they will not be used, so in the wizard the user can 'uncheck' "linq" and these specific files would not be included.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you must do (through the iwizard):

1. wait for the project file to be written do disk
2. open it
3. read what files are included
4. display a UI so user can deselect.
5. modify the project file
6. save project file
7. delete the deselected files from disk

That should do what you want. (I am not sure which event in the IWizard you do this, but I'm sure one of the events are after the project files have been written and before the project gets openened. This is your window to do the change).